# SQL - turn records to columns

Tags: sql, pivot, rows

I have a table like this:
interval class
01-02    class1
02-03    class2
03-04    class1
04-05    class2
05-06    class1

and i want result like this

```
class1 class2
01-02  02-03
03-04  04-05
05-06  NULL
```

First line are column names

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi, any particular database engine ?

Comment: Microsoft SQl Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the rows by classes and then use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when class = 'class1' then interval end) as class1,
       max(case when class = 'class2' then interval end) as class2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by class order by interval) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: It works fine. Thanks.  I wonder if exists a solution using pivot....

Comment: @CornelMilitaru . . . Probably.  But why bother?  It is more cumbersome and is not Standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is a FIXED number of columns, you can do this using a SELECT with GROUP BY.
Let me show you an example  over the Table “T_Capital_Rainfall_Q” (see below):

```
  SELECT  Capital, Cal_Year
        , Max(Iif(Quart="Q1", Quart_Rainfall, Null)) AS Q1
        , Max(Iif(Quart="Q2", Quart_Rainfall, Null)) AS Q2
        , Max(Iif(Quart="Q3", Quart_Rainfall, Null)) AS Q3
        , Max(Iif(Quart="Q4", Quart_Rainfall, Null)) AS Q4
  FROM T_Capital_Rainfall_Q
  GROUP BY Capital, Cal_Year ;
```

this SQL operation above produces the following output record-list (not aligned, sorry):

```
Capital Cal_Year    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
Beijing 2018    0   4   7,8 17
Washington  2018    12.13   5.67    2.26    12.7
```

In case it is a variable number of columns, the only way is to use  TRANSFORM Query.

The table for the example above is:

```
T_Capital_Rainfall_Q
Capital Cal_Year    Quart   Quart_Rainfall
Beijing 2018    Q1  0
Beijing 2018    Q2  4
Beijing 2018    Q3  7.8
Beijing 2018    Q4  17
Washington  2018    Q1  12.13
Washington  2018    Q2  5.67
Washington  2018    Q3  2.26
Washington  2018    Q4  12.7
```

More information in [LightningGuide.net](https://lightningguide.net).